# Unclear algorithm requirement

Tags: algorithm

I don't know if this task is familiar to you, but I have to admit that it is unclear to me. If anyone has met, please explain to me. I'm not looking for a solution, just a clarification of what is required. Thank you.

Task:

For a random array of structs of type {id, value }, return a new struct, with an unique
id and a value such as the next positive integer, which isn't present in the existing
structure list and with at least one smaller integer appearing at least twice in the
same list.

For example:

a = [{id:1, value:3}, {id:2, value:7}, {id:3, value:3}, {id:4, value:1}, {id:5, value:4}]

value 1 - appears once

value 3 - appears 2 times

value 4 - appears once

value 7 - appears once

Solution: {id: 6, value: 5}

About id everything is clear, but does value (in this case 5) is there because 3x2 is 6 and value needs to be smaller than (in this case) 6?

Comment: I don't see how it relates to 3x2, looking at the rules, no. It's the next integer which isn't already in the list, and there at least one smaller integer which appears twice in the list (in this case, that integer is 3). Those rules seem fairly clearly stated, to me

Comment: The task says it all: `the next positive integer, which isn't present in the existing structure list and with at least one smaller integer appearing at least twice in the same list`. So you have to find a number that is at least twice in the list, which is `3`. You have to take the next positive integer, which would be `4`, but `4` is already in the list, so you'll try the next, which is `5`. As `5` isn't in the list, it is the solution. Am I right?

Comment: By contrast, if 3 appeared once and 7 appeared twice, then you would have to pick 8 as the next value.  Does that help to explain it?

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of structures, each with an id and a value. You need to create a new structure with a unique id and a value such that the value is the smallest positive integer that is not already present in the list, and at least one smaller integer appears at least twice in the list.

For example, given the list of structures `a`:

```
[
  {id: 1, value: 3},
  {id: 2, value: 7},
  {id: 3, value: 3},
  {id: 4, value: 1},
  {id: 5, value: 4}
]
```

The value 1 appears once, the value 3 appears twice, the value 4 appears once, and the value 7 appears once. Therefore, the solution would be a new structure with `{id: 6, value: 5}`, because 5 is the smallest positive integer that is not already present in the list and at least one smaller integer (in this case, 3) appears at least twice in the list.

If `{id: 6, value: 5}` was appended to list `a`, then the next solution would be `{id: 7, value: 6}` because 6 is the smallest integer that does not appear as a value that also has a smaller integer that appears twice (3 again.)